# Issue in my function for include files with template tag

Tags: php

In my own function, First i want to `include` one `html` file, Then if in that included file, we find another `html` file name, i want to merge content of first included file and second included file.

```
function inc($html){
$include_pattern = "\{\s*include\s*(\(|')\s*([a-zA-Z0-9-.\/-_]+)\s*(\)|')\s*\}";
preg_match_all("/$include_pattern/s",$html,$match);
if($len = count($match[0])){
$i=0;
        while($i<$len){
$file = preg_replace("/$include_pattern/s","$2",$match[0][$i]);

ob_start(); 
         include($file);
         $output = ob_get_contents();
         ob_end_clean();
//$output = $this->inc($output);
        $html = str_replace($match[0][$i],$output,$html);

$i++; 
     }
return $html;

       }
}
```

In this function, if you look at the commented part in the code, i was tried for get content of 2nd included `html` file. Imagine, if we include `1.html`, if in this included file we have `2.html`, how we can show content of `2.html` and content of `1.html` ?

If you look at image in below, its clear for understand current topic. ( i want to get result like "result box" in the image).

[image]

Comment: there has to be a better approach than this.

Comment: @Dagon, Can you explain more,please?

Comment: why not use `include('2.html');` in 1.html?

Comment: @Dagon, Because I'm trying for write this template tag, i knew there is `include('2.html');` .

Comment: what is a "template tag" ? there are many existing template engines, why not use one?

Comment: SMARTY is a good choice. But what do you want to try out here? Aren't you getting your tag from the 1.html? If so, you can parse file name and get the contents then replace it with the tag you placed. What's the problem?

Comment: Well I'm trying for build my own Template engine for my own CMS.I just asked about this issue.So, Let me know if you have idea for implementation this feature

Comment: *No*.  Do no write yet another template engine.  There are lots out there, most of them suck, but all of them *work*.

Comment: Its seems to be if you look at the next post, its clear for what happens in my function for fix bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix issue in my function. There is changed function and work well...

```
function inc($html){
$include_pattern = "\{\s*include\s*(\(|')\s*([a-zA-Z0-9-.\/-_]+)\s*(\)|')\s*\}";
preg_match_all("/$include_pattern/s",$html,$match);
if($len = count($match[0])){
$i=0;
        while($i<$len){
$file = preg_replace("/$include_pattern/s","$2",$match[0][$i]);

ob_start(); 
         include($file);
         $output = ob_get_contents();
         ob_end_clean();

        $html = str_replace($match[0][$i],$output,$html);

$i++; 
     }
return inc($html); 
       }else{
     return $html;
   }
}
```